# Binance API quoteOrderQty

Tags: python, trading, binance, binance-api-client

Problem with placing an order for spot trading in binance. I want to sell a currency and get another in the amount that I transfer by value. The API says ***:param quoteOrderQty: amount the user wants to spend (when buying) or receive (when selling)
of the quote asset, applicable to MARKET orders*** ([link](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#new-order-trade)), that is, this is exactly the argument to which I pass the amount that I want to receive when selling. Example:

```
client.create_order(symbol="BUSDUSDT", side="sell", type="MARKET",
                                                     quoteOrderQty=15)
```

after executing it, I should receive `15 USDT`, which doesn't happen. The order is filled and exactly `15 BUSD are sold`, `14.9985 USDT` are bought :)

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> MARKET orders using quoteOrderQty specifies the amount the user wants to spend (when buying) or receive (when selling) the quote asset; the correct quantity will be determined based on the market liquidity and quoteOrderQty

By using `quoteOrderQty` for `MARKET` order, server will execute the order and fill as much as possible. But the final received `quantity` can be a little bit different than `quoteOrderQty`.

Comment: Why the final quantity is just "a little bit" different than quoteOrderQty? From what I understand the former is in the unit of base asset while the latter is in the unit of quote asset, aren't they? Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

Comment: When the SELL order is submitted, there’s calculation of quantity based on quoteOrderQty=15 that needs to follow the LOT_SIZE filter rule as well (which doesn’t allow BUSDUSDT to have decimals), therefore instead of selling quoteOrderQty/market price = 15.00150015 BUSD, it’s placed with 15BUSD ( the max it can be filled based on the LOT_SIZE) and finally the market price leads to receiving 14.9985USDT. 

Hope this helps to clarify better.

Note:
- You can check the filters using https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#exchange-information